# Как сделать проверку на роль пользователя?

Tags: python, sql, бот

```
@command(name="+хелп")
async def adm(self, ctx, member=None):
    user = await self.bot.get_user(ctx.from_id)
    adm = await basa.register.main.chekc_adm(user)
    mem = re.findall(f"[0-9]+", member)[0]
    print(mem is self.my_awesome_dict[2] == 'Хелпер')
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send("Перешлите сообщение или укажите айди пользователя")
    if member is self.my_awesome_dict[2] == adm:
        await ctx.send("Пользователь имеет данную роль")
    elif self.my_awesome_dict[6] >= adm:
        mem = re.findall(f"[0-9]+", member)[0]
        await ctx.send(format(user.first_name) + ", выдал роль администратора пользователю " + "@id" + format(str(mem)))
        await basa.register.main.adm(int(mem))
    else:
        await ctx.send("Не достаточно прав")
```

Как сделать проверку на наличие роли пользователя кому пытаешься выдать роль?

```
if member is self.my_awesome_dict[2] == adm:
        await ctx.send("Пользователь имеет данную роль")
```

self.my_awesome_dict[2] - это роль хелпер

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать, что бы когда у пользователя кому хочу выдать роль ''Хелпер'' если уже имеется эта роль или выше то пишет 'Пользователь имеет данную роль'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if self.my_awesome_dict[2] in member.roles:
    await ctx.send("Пользователь имеет данную роль")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]